# How can I select the input value after clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3-composition-api

When I click on Edit button, whatever prefetched value of input is there should be selected, so that it can be edited further.
What shall I write in function to highlight/select the msg value which can be edited?

[image]

Comment: There is the [`HTMLInputElement.select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) method.

Comment: And no, answers are answers, not comments, and shall be given as such.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Include the code as text, and an image of something if needed.

Comment: You shouldn't have backticks at the start and end of your code.

Comment: Here's an example implementation: [Vue Playground](https://dub.sh/bvCtei3). It does assume that target names are "safe" for simple interpolation into the selector. You can use whatever method you want for linking the button and input, though; the `.select()` is the important part.

Comment: Can you expand as to how this will be used? Is there just a single pair like this, or are there many input/button pairs? Will it be used as a composable or just plain code? Do you specifically want a template ref, a selector-based approach, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="handleClick">CLick me </button>
    <input ref="myInputRef" v-model="msg" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const msg = ref('World');
const myInputRef = ref(null)

function handleClick() {
  if (myInputRef.value) {
    myInputRef.value.select();
  }
}
</script>
```

I believe this is how you can solve this issue: create a ref for the input element and call the `.select()` method to select the content.